# Proving convergence of a sequence Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let a sequence $b_n$ be periodic.

Prove that

$$x_n={\frac{b_1 + \cdots + b_n}{n}}$$

converges.

I think that $x_{n}$ eventually converges to $L = \dfrac{b_1 + \cdots + b_p}{p}$ where $P$ is the period.

From here the next step I would think would be to apply the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of convergence, but I am still working on this step. I understand that I have to find an index $N$ s.t for every index n greater than $N$   $|x_{n} - L| < \epsilon$.

Any hints on whether or not I am going in the right direction? I am fairly certain my approach is incorrect, but I am trying my best to understand.

Best Regards,
tenki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\overbrace{\overbrace{b_1+\cdots+b_p}^\text{1st} + \overbrace{b_1+\cdots + b_p}^\text{2nd} + \overbrace{b_1+\cdots+b_p}^\text{3rd} + \cdots+\overbrace{b_1+\cdots+b_p}^{\text{$k$th}}} + \overbrace{b_1+\cdots+b_\ell}^{\ell\le p}}{kp+\ell}
$$

If $\ell=\text{either $0$ or $p$}$ then it is trivial that the quantity above is $\dfrac{b_1+\cdots+b_p}{p}$.  As $\ell$ goes from $1$ to $p$, try to find bounds on the biggest and smallest values that the average above can have.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the maximum value is simply the first element that contains max($b_1,\cdots , b_p$) and the min being the first element that contains min($b_1, \cdots , b_p$)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as you go through the sequence from the end of the $k$th group to the end of the $(k+1)$th group, you start at the average value of the $b$s and return to it.  You should try to show that that fluctuation gets smaller as $k$ increases, and can be made as small as desired by making $k$ big enough.

Comment: Got it thanks a bunch!